# how to add common view in all views using angular?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

can you please tell me how to common view in all view ?I have a panel I need to show that panel in all view ?can you please tell me how it is possible?

Here is my panel 
http://plnkr.co/edit/rt5dAwhVzvP14UDR2jc7?p=preview

Now I need to show in panel in both two views how it is possible ?
http://plnkr.co/edit/KnUGjEBOhiBAp0e6ThIl?p=preview
I am able to add common ..is it the best way to implement

```
  <body>
  <a  class="large button toggle" pageslide="right" ps-speed="0.8" href="#demo-right">Open Demo</a>
  <div style="padding:20px" id="demo-right">
                <h2>Hello Pageslide</h2>
                <p>Put here whatever you want</p>
                <a id="demo-right-close"i class="button" >Close</a>
            </div>
      <ng-view></ng-view>
  </body>
```

add toggle the panel using the same button ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, create the panel as a directive and then include it in each view that you wish for it to appear in?

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Pay particular attention to this section:

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#template-expanding-directive

Comment: can you please make a plunker

Comment: this is not a anwer..please remove it if you know it then share it

Comment: I've told you how to do it, as per the title of the question. I've given you a link that explains the process in vast detail. I'm not going to do it for you, that's not what StackOverflow is for.

Comment: but sir I am able to add view is both view .but Question is it a best way